# How to determine what appstore user is using?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an application with in-app purchase ability in it.

My Client has a pricing structure. so in different countries he is offering different subscriptions.

He worked it out Different Tiers (About 4 different Tiers).

Now my question is how do I determine which AppStore user account belongs to in order to call the correct Product ID? I dont think GEO location is the correct approach.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using NSLocale would be the best possible solution for determining the user's country.

Here's how it would be done:

```
// Get user's country code based on currentLocale
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];

if ([countryCode isEqualToString:@"US"]){
    // US
}
```

However, since there's no guarantee that the user won't change their international settings, you might have no choice but to release separate apps, one for a US audience, one for UK audience, etc.